# How can I rid of this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code on the line that is mentioned as error:

```
$avia_config['color_sets'] = (
    'header_color'      => 'Logo Area',
    'main_color'        => 'Main Content',
    'alternate_color'   => 'Alternate Content,
    'footer_color'      => 'Footer
    'socket_color'      => 'Socket'
);
```

Comment: looks like missing `',` at `'Footer` and `'` at Alternate Content

Comment: it's not working

Comment: did you change it ? is so paste you new code

Comment: Here is the new code.Still showing same error,

$avia_config['color_sets'] = (
    'header_color'      => 'Logo Area',
    'main_color'        => 'Main Content',
    'alternate_color'   => 'Alternate Content',
    'footer_color'      => 'Footer',
    'socket_color'      => 'Socket'
 );

Comment: [Here is edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54269974/edit)

Comment: Arrays are defined using either the "array" keyword and parentheses (`array( 'key' => 'value' )`) or using square brackets (`[ 'key' => 'value' ]`). Using parentheses without the "array" keyword is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one :

```
$avia_config['color_sets'] = array(
    'header_color'      => 'Logo Area',
    'main_color'        => 'Main Content',
    'alternate_color'   => 'Alternate Content',
    'footer_color'      => 'Footer',
    'socket_color'      => 'Socket'
);
```

you are missing the `array` keyword and `',` at 'Footer and `'` at Alternate Content

Comment: use an IDE with php code checker link Visual Studio Code and php-intellisense (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php), it will solve you error like this

Comment: Can you see what is the problem here in the code

(!function_exists('avia_theme_update_filter'))
{
 avia_theme_update_filter( $data )
 {
  (current_theme_supports(via_improved_backend_style'))
  {
   $data['icon'] = 'new/arrow-repeat-two-7@3x.png';
  }
  return $data;
 }
 
 add_filter('avf_update_theme_tab, 'avia_theme_update_filter', 30, 1);
}

Comment: @user117635 This is not part of the question and nobody wants to read this amount of code in comments. Just open a new question (one issue per question)